# Why is build apk slower than in the emulator?

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I was trying to optimize react-native app, after watching the 2017 video, I found out that there is a dev mode, after I found it in the settings file,
I turned off the
{
**"dev": false,

"minify": true,**
}
and then I was surprised how fast my application became, but when I build it and expo gave me an apk file, on my phone I found that everything is as slow as if dev mode is on...

How can I get the speed that is when the dev mode is turned off?
{
**"expo": "~40.0.1",

"react": "16.13.1",

"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-40.0.1.tar.gz",**
}

Comment: Can you provide the 2017 video link?

Comment: @KamalHossain it video is in russian